# not working dropdown list in edit view in mvc4 razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

am unable to get correct value from drop down in mvc4. my edit view code is

```
@Html.DropDownList("IDCountry", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.IDCountry, 
    new { @class = "span6" })
```

if i use below code am able to get correct value but am unable to apply style for dropdownlist

```
@Html.DropDownList("IDCountry",String.empty)
```

please solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

You should not use the same value (`IDCountry`) as first and second argument for the dropdown. The first argument represents the value to bind the dropdown to while the second represents the available values. So:

```
@Html.DropDownList(
    "SelectedCountryID", 
    (IEnumerable)ViewBag.IDCountry, 
    new { @class = "span6" }
)
```

To avoid all those confusions with Dropdowns I would recommend you using a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string SelectedCountryID { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Countries { get; set; }
}
```

and then your controller action will populate and pass this view model to the view:

```
public class HomeController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new MyViewModel();
        // preselected an element with Value = "2"
        model.SelectedCountryID = "2";

        // obviously those values could come from a database or something
        model.Countries = new[]
        {
            new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "Country 1" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "Country 2" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "Country 3" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "4", Text = "Country 4" },
        };

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
    {
        return Content("Thanks for selecting country ID: " + model.SelectedCountryID);
    }
}
```

and finally in your view use the strongly typed helper:

```
@model MyViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.SelectedCountryID)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(
            x => x.SelectedCountryID, 
            Model.Countries, 
            new { @class = "span6" }
        )
    </div>

    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

See how the very instant you **STOP** using ViewBag and remove absolutely all traces from it in your application everything becomes crystal clear?

Comment: code is not written by me. not possible to change in your way now,so is there any way to apply CSS for below type of code @Html.DropDownList("IDCountry",String.empty)

Comment: Yes, you could use the example shown in the first part of my answer.

Comment: @Anilreddy agree with Darin... you can re-write anything and it should be that hard givin he gave you all examples. And i tested them they work.